# Looping through gifs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to duplicate an banner ad like this one but I need it to loop through three animated gifs.

Here is the sample code I have been modifying here:

```
// randomization
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

var images = new Array("<div class='ad'><a href = 'https://www.poundstopocket.co.uk/buildapp' target='_blank'>
<img src='https://www.poundstopocket.co.uk/pound-place/wp-content/themes/shaken-grid-premium/images/1.gif' alt='Visit Computer Hope'></a></div>", 
"<div class='ad'><a href = 'https://www.poundstopocket.co.uk/straightforwardapp' target='_blank'><img src='https://www.poundstopocket.co.uk/pound-place/wp-content/themes/shaken-grid-premium/images/2.gif' alt='Computer History'></a></div>", 
"<div class='ad'><a href = 'https://www.poundstopocket.co.uk/nohiddenfeesapp' target='_blank'><img src='https://www.poundstopocket.co.uk/pound-place/wp-content/themes/shaken-grid-premium/images/3.gif' alt='Visit Computer Hope'></a></div>")
// loop
setInterval(function() {
    $('.ad').html(images[index])
    if(index == 2){ 
        index = 0; 
    }else{ 
        index++; 
    }
}, 5000);
```

which includes most of the jscript and the images from the website.

This loop does not work like I need it to for my own purposes I need the loop to reset and start over at 0,1 or 2 since the initial script in randomizing I would like to keep that part but continuously loop 3 5 or 6 second gifs.

Comment: why are you using an array like that, did you try to put the div in your HTML and then play with `fadeOut()` & `fadeIn()` ?

Comment: Thanks this is the div <div class="ad"></div> and no I did not try the fade in and out because I wanted the loop to work first and it does not see here http://jsfiddle.net/2ZgG3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way of doing this - randomise the order of your array first.

```
images.sort(function() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); });
```

Then

```
var ad = $('.ad'), next = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    ad.html(images[next]);
    next = images[next+1] ? next+1 : 0;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried add that to my image array script here and it yielded nothing but your code looks much cleaner. http://jsfiddle.net/2ZgG3/1/

Comment: There is still a pause though before the first gif loads does there need to be a preload of the first random gif?